# Does the List of Most Wanted Terrorists of CS:CZDS uses real pictures?

Tags: counter-strike-condition-zero

On Counter-Strike: Condition Zero Deleted Scenes, there is a training map for testing the game items and weapons.

When you start the map, you need to take an elevator that has a poster with "Most Wanted Terrorists".

[image]
[image]

Are the pictures on this list real or they were created for the game? If the pictures are real, are they real terrorists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire image is real. The FBI released this list of their ["Most Wanted Terrorists"](https://web.archive.org/web/20011010215326/http://www.fbi.gov/mostwant/terrorists/fugitives.htm) shortly after the September 11 attacks. ([Here's the current version of the list.](https://www.fbi.gov/wanted/wanted_terrorists))

Here's a higher-resolution version of the poster. Many of the individuals on the list have since been killed or captured.

[image]